# Unable to run "ng build" Angular 12.1.0

Tags: angular-cli

I've just made a new Angular project with ng new app-name but when i try to build a production release i get the following error:

```
Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)
...An unhandled exception occurred: 
ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'E:\Angular\museum-kiosk\dist\museum-kiosk'
See "C:\Users\imytyuk\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-dPVXDC\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

While in the log file i got this:

```
[error] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'E:\Angular\museum-kiosk\dist\museum-kiosk'
    at Object.statSync (node:fs:1527:3)
    at __node_internal_ (node:internal/fs/utils:767:8)
    at Object.rmdirSync (node:fs:1147:15)
    at Object.deleteOutputDir (E:\Angular\museum-kiosk\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\delete-output-dir.js:21:10)
    at initialize (E:\Angular\museum-kiosk\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\browser\index.js:86:17)
    at async SwitchMapSubscriber.project (E:\Angular\museum-kiosk\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\browser\index.js:114:17)
```

I've tried to add the mkdir dist in my package.json > build but nothing changed...

I've tried to change
`import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';` to `import { AppModule } from './app/';` in main.ts, but nothing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell this is a problem with `@angular-devkit/build-angular` which is hopefully being worked on.

It can be overcome by running (in your case)

```
mkdirp dist\museum-kiosk
```

before you build.

Comment: damn i've created the dist folder but forgot the museum-kiosk one, working as well, thanks!